# Using Python COM to select files in windows explorer?

Tags: python, windows, com, automation

Is it possible using Python COM to select files inside of the windows explorer? For example, I am trying to get all "*.txt" files inside of windows explore highlighted without having to select them with the mouse, or without other keyboard gymnastics.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this useful for you, but you might be able to register a pyhook module and make it listen to which window you are selecting, once you get the path then you can process it with python listdir()

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: Thanks. That helps. The only other question is not how to select the items in the Windows Explorer window. It turns out the object model for that is extremely complicated and I don't think it can be done without employing the NET framework.